# can I limit how often monit will alert?

Tags: monit

Sometimes monit spams alerts faster than the devops can read them. It's not false alarms, things have gone crazy. But yet there is no need to spray alerts all over the place, a few would be sufficient to draw attention.

Question is: **Is it possible to rate limit alerts from monit?** Of course I could just hack something together myself, but that would be foolish if monit already has a rate limit somehow.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but I'll answer anyway.
Monit only sends alarms once, but if there are several different alarms pending, multiple alarms will be sent.
There is no limit to the alarms sent by Monit, you can only limit certain alarms, see https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#ALERT-MESSAGES